# Time manipulation for android

Tags: android

Hi every one i want to devolepe an Alarm App i get the sunrise and sunset time from webservice now i need to manipulate these timing my date store in string when i calculate difference it give correct result when i add two time values it cause problem like

```
 i try it like below to get the manipulated time that i applied manipulation  but 
 it give wrong result 

 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss");

 Date Date1 = sdf.parse(sunrsetat);
 Date Date2 = sdf.parse("00:12:00");
 long millse = Date1.getTime() + Date2.getTime();
 long mills = Math.abs(millse);
 int Hours = (int) (mills/(60*60*1000));<------ here it give hour 09 and it must be 19 
 int Mins = (int) (mills/(1000*60)) % 60;
 long Secs = (int) (mills / 1000) % 60;
 String time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", Hours, Mins, Secs);
 hanfiaiftaritime.setText(time);
```

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Comment: I solved it thanks ..... look at accepted answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error occurs because Date.getTime() returns millis since Jan 1, 1970, so your mills field has value (assuming date1 < date2) of 2*date1 + difference-in-millis-date2-date1. ([http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29))

Solution: use Calendar class.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date1);
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, (int) date2.getTime() / 1000);
long millse = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

In this case computing hours/mins/seconds becomes redundant cause you can use [http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) like this:

```
int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```